# Converting an arraylist to a normal array

Tags: java, jsp

I was wondering if anyone would be able to show me how to convert an arraylist to normal array in Jsp?

Answer (score 1):

```
yourArrayList.toArray()
```

but this won't be generic.. to use the generic version, let's assume you've got an `ArrayList<Yourclass>`. Just do:

```
YourClass[] array = yourArrayList.toArray(new YourClass[0]);
```

A side note: **JSP** is not a language but a container of Java code and html so what you need is **Java** code..

Comment: Here you created an empty array (new YourClass[0]) which is soon discarded. This would be much better: yourArrayList.toArray(new YourClass[*yourArrayList.size()*]); The same array will be returned.